# Is there an R function to see how them median value is changing with regards to 2 categorical variables?

Tags: r, data-visualization, data-analysis

[image: MY DATA SET]

This is my data and I need to calculate a new variable called wealth; wealth= total assets- total debt. I need to see the change in median wealth overtime according to race and education. However, when I plot a box plot it only gives me points rather than a box, can someone explain a better way of doing this or tell me what am I doing wrong.

This is my current code, I'm only using race right now but ill facet wrap with educationonce I figure out whats wrong .

```
df$education <- as.factor(df$education)

df$race <- as.factor(df$race)

plot1 <- df %>%
  mutate(wealth = asset_total -debt_tota)) %>%
  select(race,wealth)

ggplot(plot1,aes(x=race,y=wealth))+geom_boxplot()
```

Comment: You need to show us what your are doing for us to be able to tell you what you are doing wrong. What code are you using to create your boxplot?

Comment: Done, please have a look now.

Comment: Looks fine. Are you sure your boxplot isn't squished and the dots you're seeing are the outliers? Could happen if your data has a long tail.

Comment: If you need more help than that, please post a small subset of your data reproducibly - `dput` is the best way to do that. `dput(plot1[1:10, ])` would be great.

Comment: No obvious reason for a Stata tag. I've edited it out.